# XSLT: extract node value from escaped XML section

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML doc:

```
<Request>
  <Header>
    <TransactionId>132456789</TransactionId>
    <ExternalId>4544455</ExternalId>
  </Header>
  <Reply>
&lt;S:Envelope&gt;
  &lt;S:Body&gt;
    &lt;ns2:CreateAccountResponse&gt;
      &lt;username&gt;123456789@example.com&lt;/username&gt;
    &lt;/ns2:CreateAccountResponse&gt;
  &lt;/S:Body&gt;
&lt;/S:Envelope&gt;
</Reply>
</Request>
```

The values inside `Reply` element is also XML data.

I need to use XSL spreadsheet to extract the username element's value . i.e. `123456789@abc.net`   and use it as the value of another element.

Currently I am doing the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="reply" select="/Request/Reply">
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Request>
            <Header>
                <TransactionId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Request/Header/TransactionId"/>
                </TransactionId>
                <ExternalId><xsl:value-of select="Request/Header/ExternalId"/>
                </ExternalId>
            </Header>

            <Job>
                <CreateUserResponse>
                    <AccountUserName>

                        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($reply)/node()  "/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$reply//username"/>
                    </AccountUserName>

                </CreateUserResponse>
            </Job>
        </Request>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I am unable to just get the `username` value from this XSL. 
I need this value to become the value of the `<AccountUserName>` element

Currently, this is the XML that I get after the transformation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/internetdevice" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
    <Header>
        <TransactionId>132456789</TransactionId>
        <ExternalId>4544455</ExternalId>
    </Header>
    <Job>
        <CreateUserResponse>
            <AccountUserName>&lt;S:Envelope&gt;
                &lt;S:Body&gt;
                &lt;ns2:CreateAccountResponse&gt;
                &lt;username&gt;123456789@example.com&lt;/username&gt;
                &lt;/ns2:CreateAccountResponse&gt;
                &lt;/S:Body&gt;
                &lt;/S:Envelope&gt;</AccountUserName>
        </CreateUserResponse>
    </Job>
</Request>
```

Any ideas / suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not really CDATA. Not that it matters in this context.

Answer (score 1):

The `node-set` function doesn't parse XML like this, its purpose is to convert a "result tree fragment" (an `xsl:variable` with a body) back into a node set you can navigate into.

Instead you need to look for an appropriate "parser" extension function for the xslt processor you're using. Saxon PE/EE provides [saxon:parse](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/extensions/functions/parse.html), or look at the documentation for your processor if you're using a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to extract a string from inside the `Reply` node, you don't have to convert it into a node. You can search for the `&lt;username&gt;` strings and get the text in between using `substring` functions. The XPath expression:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//Reply,'&lt;username&gt;'),'&lt;/username&gt;')
```

will return the string between `&lt;username&gt;` and `&lt;/username&gt;` in the `Reply` node.

You can write a much simpler XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Request">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Header" />
            <Job>
                <CreateUserResponse>
                    <AccountUserName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(Reply,'&lt;username&gt;'),'&lt;/username&gt;')"/>
                    </AccountUserName>
                </CreateUserResponse>
            </Job>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will generate the following result XML containing the `username`:

```
<Request>
   <Header>
        <TransactionId>132456789</TransactionId>
        <ExternalId>4544455</ExternalId>
    </Header>
   <Job>
      <CreateUserResponse>
         <AccountUserName>123456789@example.com</AccountUserName>
      </CreateUserResponse>
   </Job>
</Request>
```

If you need to manipulate the data in the nodes, you can do it using XSLT 2.0 replacing the angle brackets and re-processing the result. See the answer to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374012/xslt-transform-with-source-containing-lt-and-gt/23375747#23375747)** which contains an example.