# Using class attribute in xsl tag

Tags: html, xml, xslt

tried searching the forums but wasn't finding what I needed so I thought I'd ask.  I am new to XSL so I know next to nothing about how to parse it, but can understand what is written a bit, so this question is going to be I think fairly easy, I just have no clue cause I've never used XSL before.  So forgive me if I use the odd/wrong terminology.

Background, the XML I am taking from the database, is really straight forward, and uses just a simple copy-of statement to copy the nodes because most are just straight html.  This is a sample part of the code that is returned to me it looks like the following:

```
<tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="Bold Label Center">1</td>
                <td class="Bold Label Stub Left">Area</td>
                <td class="Bold Right">3.68</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Bold Label Center">2</td>
                <td Indentation="2" class="Bold Label Stub Left">United States</td>
                <td class="Bold Right">7.68</td>
          </tr>
             <tr>
                <td class="Bold Label Center">3</td>
                <td Indentation="6" class="Label Stub Left">Oregon</td>
                <td class="Right">2.7</td>                    
           </tr>
 etc....
           <tr>
             <td class="Label Center">23</td>
             <td Indentation="6" class="Label Stub Left">Portland&lt;sup&gt;1&lt;/sup&gt;</td>
            <td class="Right">12.345</td>
           </tr>
</tbody>
```

XSL

```
    <xsl:for-each select="div[@class='HtmlTable']/table">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <xsl:copy-of select="tbody"/>       
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

This is of course fine, I've taken out some other code just to keep it simple.  But what I don't know how to do, is to make the TD class attribute be part of the TD tags.  So I would like the output to ideally be for example in the first lines output to be:

```
<TR><TD align=center><B>1</B></TD><TD align=left><B>Area</B></TD>
<TD align=right>3.68</TD></TR>
```

Right now the output of just the copy of course doesn't transfer those kind of attributes which I don't know how to do.

I also of course would like to indent a few items (maybe nbsp; or perhaps style pixels), and get the superscript tag to work.

I am sure this is really simple but this is all new to me and I am just spinning my wheels and going nowhere.  Any help would be appreciated, and my gut feeling is that this is really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a template that will select the `<td>` nodes, and check if the `class` atrribute contains `Center`, `Left`, or `Right`. Then you generate the `td` with the appropriate `align` attribute.

Here is a simple way to do it, based on your example.

Replace your `copy-of` with an `apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="div[@class='HtmlTable']/table">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tbody"/>       
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Add templates for `tbody` and `tr` (if you have many simple copies like this, an *identity transform* can deal with all of them):

```
<xsl:template match="tbody">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tr"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="td"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And add templates for each `td` align case:

```
<xsl:template match="td[contains(@class, 'Center')]">
    <td align="center">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="td[contains(@class, 'Left')]">
    <td align="left">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="td[contains(@class, 'Right')]">
    <td align="right">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

This will generate a table with `td` elements containing `align` attributes instead of class selectors.

See a working example here: **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Yp)**

Comment: Well, that does work well, and I used it for the bold item too. Now if I could figure out how to dynamically use the Indentation I think I am set... can't quite get the template to work and use the value @indentation to use as pixels  * a constant for style padding-left

Comment: You can. If you are in any template that matches a `td` you can use something like `<td style="padding-left: {@Indentation * 2}px"/>` which would produce `<td style="padding-left: 12px"/>` if `@Indentation` is `6`, for example. The curly braces allow you to embed an XPath expression in a static tag (as if you were using a `<xsl:value-of select>` in there. They are called *Attribute Value Templates*.

Comment: This is not the only solution. There are also many ways to do the same things in XSLT. You could also do the same with `for-each` and `if`, but it's usually better to use recursive templates with conditional selections using XPath predicates for non-sequential looping and conditionals, and rarely use `for-each` and `if/choose`. If you can dedicate some time to study some XPath and XSLT which follows these functional language practices, working with XSLT and XPath will become much easier.

Comment: yeah I was trying actually <xsl:value of ... in the TD tag, but kept getting an error cause you couldn't have a "<" in it of course.  Glad to see there is a way out of it with the curlys, did not know/find that one out. Tried it and it worked.  Debating using a + 15 or a * 2 or something cosmetics, but that's fidly bits at this point.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to integrate the disable-output-escaping factor in the node copy... it's messing up my <sup> tag and writing it as a literal... hmm..

Comment: You won't be able to convert that easily. The whole node is loaded by XSLT as a *string*. `disable-output-escaping` is for `xsl:text` (created in the stylesheet) that contains tags that you don't want to escape. The best you can do in your case is to parse the string using `substring()` functions, extract the code you want (tag names, tag values) and rebuild the tags (using `xs:element`). If you are using XSLT 2.0 there are some other tricks.

Comment: I am thinking this is getting a bit convoluted.  I think I do have XSLT 2.0 available, what would I use either with or instead of the copy-of constructs, to make this happen?

Comment: See if [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374012/xslt-transform-with-source-containing-lt-and-gt/23375747#23375747) helps. If not, you might prefer to ask a new question focusing on that problem.